# Can Use Magic Device allow casting an off-list spell from a runestaff?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items, skills

Is it possible for a creature to succeed on a Use Magic Device skill check to emulate a class feature so as to enable the creature to employ a runestaff to cast spells not on the creature's spell list?

For example, can a duskblade succeed on a Use Magic Device skill check so as to use a runestaff to cast the spell *displacement*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Use Magic Device* has a specific list of things you're allowed to emulate, one of which is "Emulate a Class Feature". If you wish to use the runestaff in a way your class doesn't allow, you can instead emulate the spellcasting ability of a different class.

The "Use A Wand" ability specifically allows you to use spell trigger items, not just wands. It has the same DC as "Emulate a Class Feature".

Whether you need two checks (to use a spell trigger item from a spell list you don't have with a spell that's not in the runestaff) or just one is a matter of DM discretion.

Comment: This is correct, but it may be worth noting how unlikely this was to be intended, seeing how difficult WotC made off-list spellcasting in general. (Then again, maybe they *didn’t*, since Extra Spell arguably works from other lists.)

Comment: Is this a good place to bring up Lidda and the magic chalice? (To summarize, the rules tacitly allow by example *any* creature that succeeds on a Use Magic Device skill check to emulate the appropriate class feature to activate a runestaff, whether or not she can cast spells at all—see *PH* 86. Most DMs disagree, however.)

Comment: This is interesting, with this method its possible to surpass some limitations from duskblade and hexblade and make then more versatile with more protection, battlefield control and scouting spells.

Comment: As a side comment, psionics specifically allow for off-list acquisition via certain methods (usually the Expanded Knowledge feat), so perhaps that could be taken as RAI regarding the general concept of off-list acquisitions.